# PointerCapturing OnLoad

Tags: javascript

I try to use pointercapture and track mouse position outside browser window, but it works right only when mousedown, I've tried to simulate mousedown event but it works only when hovering element ( could anyone help me to find the right way to capture pointer and track it include outside the browser window plz.

```
var evt = new MouseEvent("pointerdown", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
    /* whatever properties you want to give it */
}),
    capture = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');

function beginCapture(e) {
capture.onpointermove = capturing;
capture.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
}

function capturing(e) {
console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

capture.onpointerdown = beginCapture;
capture.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there is no way to track the mouse/pointer position outside of the browser window. However some browsers might continue firing a mousemove event when the user began a drag operation.